# iOS 10.2 - Activate Retina Flash instead of Back LED with Torch

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, retina

Is there a way to specify to the device that when one sets `setTorchModeOnWithLevel` that they would activate the Retina Flash (iPhone6s/7's front facing flash) instead of the back True-Tone LED Flash?

The following standard code appears to only be able to activate the rear LED:

```
AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInDualCamera,
     mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .front)
try device.lockForConfiguration();
let torchOn = !device.isTorchActive;
try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0);
device.unlockForConfiguration();
```

Does an API exist within iOS for one to have access to the Retina Flash?

Comment: Is your capture device the front camera? (AVCaptureDevicePosition.front)

Comment: @Emptyless: Yes, I am using the constructor where I pass in "position: .front" (updated question with the constructor). Any ideas as to why it may not be showing? Thanks.

Comment: `AVCaptureDevice` also has a bunch of properties for `flash` (separate from `torch`). Have you tried those? More info: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388116-flashmode

Comment: @DaveWeston It seems like the flash properties are deprecated, any other suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the flash settings have moved to `AVCapturePhotoSettings` as of iOS 10. Reference for this class is: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings

Comment: This video from WWDC 2016 might help: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/501/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK iOS **DON'T** have any API specific to Retina Flash. *(as of dated iOS 10.2)*

From Apple developer [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21694)

> Retina Flash iPhone 6s and 6s Plus contain a custom display chip that
>   allows the retina display to briefly flash 3 times brighter than its
>   usual maximum illuminance.  No new API was added to support this
>   feature.  Since iOS 4, AVCaptureDevice has supported the `-hasFlash`,
>   `-isFlashModeSupported:` and `-flashMode` properties.  The iPhone 6s
>   and 6s Plus front-facing cameras are the first front-facing iOS
>   cameras to respond YES to the `-hasFlash` property.  By setting the
>   front-facing camera's flashMode to `AVCaptureFlashModeOn` or
>   `AVCaptureFlashModeAuto`, the retina flash fires when a still image is
>   captured (see `AVCaptureStillImageOutput’s
>   captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:`),
>   just as the True Tone flash fires for rear-facing camera stills.

So to make your code to work check `-hasFlash` and then set the Flash mode to auto or on.

Comment: Is there any way to perform a Retina Flash without taking a picture, or is that a necessity?

Comment: @JakeChasan we cannot trigger retina flash without taking picture. I have been trying to get that as well. but from apple documentation there is no options.